# Can't interact with seekbar or replay audio file with Audio.js in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html5-audio

I am using audio.js to have multiple audios on my webpage. It works fine in FF and Safari. But there is a problem when it runs in chrome. The mouse can't click on the seek bar and I can't replay the file once it completes playing.  The application is built on ASP.NET MVC 3

```
<audio id="sample-play" src="@Url.Action("GetFile", new { Id = item.Id })" preload="none"></audio>
```

Here is what GetFile action returns

```
return this.File(filePath, "audio/mp3");
```

here is the script

```
audiojs.events.ready(function () {
    var as = audiojs.createAll();
});
```

I am currently running it on localhost. Chrome version: 28, FF version: 22.

Here is the request header which I got from

```
this.request.headers
```

`{Connection=keep-alive&Accept=*%2f*&Accept-Encoding=gzip%2cdeflate%2csdch&Accept-Language=en-US%2cen%3bq%3d0.8&Cookie=__RequestVerificationToken_Lw__%3dTIPbaVPpy5%2bOnAKy%2fFv4hWgreq6hDdaTYCGFbyMUxL%2fdnUFKgSvH1rXSGnU2KiJYh8ZCIqnMkYa%2bQRtm1Aijprhk0l91X3MSfD6lqeBczYJduNNQA%2fil7wyjjzV6qLBIPx9JiEYMNf%2fxSVoFAElA8LUtVmQmvjsELSaiN7F4w8c%3d%3b+.ASPXAUTH%3d0624064511A4221C39B071FE807A062032A48959CF83584ADAE9D248B3E0E16BCEAC716B812DFD0992FD9F1003BC46FCFCF1C8220286316B36E0C30B6C2D73CC71220C1D00BE3A6D1B9C2C4AD3AC7000425E8F5E2D2F07819BD0367223716A4DA8163EDD49FEC7EA902E9999A4D71C42782533C56A549E561C966CD2D38BBA14&Host=localhost%3a13308&Referer=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a13308%2f&User-Agent=Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1%3b+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f28.0.1500.95+Safari%2f537.36}`

and what quickwatch on the return value of GetFile() action method shows

`base: System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult

contenttype: "audio/mp3"

fileName: "D:\\Workspace\\37595600298.mp3"`

Comment: Can you post the request and response headers?

Comment: @idbehold I have edited the post. I am new to ASP.NET MVC and web development, so please pardon me if this isn't what you asked me for.